# dll with access violation (code 0xc0000005)

Tags: c++, c

## Background

Source code `A` written in C which should not be modified defines the following:

```c
// fsm.h
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef signed char int8;

typeof struct {
   uint8 var1;
   int8 var2;
   uint8 var3;
} Fsm

// fsm.c
Fsm fsm;
```

Source code `B` written in C++, which is used to observe values of different variables in while `A` is running, defines the following:

```cpp
// .hpp
typedef enum {
   STR_UINT8,
   STR_INT8,
} DataType;

typedef struct {
   DataType dtype;
   void* addr;
} ScopeVar;


// .cpp
std::map<std::string, ScopeVar> g_scope= {
   { "var1", {.dtype=STR_UINT8, .addr=&fsm.var1},
   { "var2", {.dtype=STR_INT8, .addr=&fsm.var2 },
}；
```

I attempt to record the values of var1 and var2 while `A` is running.

Note: `A` is running in embbed device in reality and it can alse be run in simulation software in the case that it's compiled into .dll.

## Problem

### Usage

At each iteration of executing task `A`, I collect data by the following:

```cpp
std::string vals;
for(auto iter = g_scope.begin();iter!=g_scope.end();iter++) {
   switch (g_scope[iter->first].dtype) {
       case STR_UINT8:
           vals = std::to_string(*static_cast<uint8*>(g_scope[iter->first].addr));
           break;
       case STR_INT8:
           vals = std::to_string(*static_cast<int8*>(g_scope[iter->first].addr));
           break;
    }
    // do something with vals....
}
```

the compiled dll can't be correctly executed and the simulation shows `access violation(code 0xc0000005) at 0x7ff8dd7aae82: Bad read on 0x0`.

### Solution

I debug serveral times, and find something wired

1. the value of pointer can be read, but can't pass to other function

```cpp
std::string vals;
for(auto iter = g_scope.begin();iter!=g_scope.end();iter++) {
   uint8 a;
   switch (g_scope[iter->first].dtype) {
       case STR_UINT8:
           a = *static_cast<uint8*>(g_scope[iter->first].addr); // without next line, it runs well
           vals = std::to_string(a); // with this line, it throws exception of access violation
           observer.log(a); // observer is a instance of spdlog, I found value of a is recorded in log file, but exception is thrown immediately after runing this.
           break;
       case STR_INT8:
           vals = std::to_string(*static_cast<int8*>(g_scope[iter->first].addr));
           break;
    }
    // do something with vals....
}
```

2. I tried to replace pointer with function, it failed as well.
3. I tried to use `&fsm+offsetof(var1)` as pointer, it failed as well.

So, how can I access the value of member of a struct by its pointer safely?

Comment: Your code didn't compile, but after I fixed it to compile it works fine with no exceptions: https://onlinegdb.com/4lcOcDJu_8

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Appreciate!  You remind me review my code, I finally find that a superset of g_scope called g_scopeLabels is iterated instead of g_scope itself! This cause non-exist key of g_scope is accessed, which lead to that exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I review my code again and finally find that a superset of `g_scope` called `g_scopeLabels` is iterated instead of `g_scope` itself! This cause non-exist key of `g_scope` is accessed, which lead to that exception.